# Não consigo acessar valores fora de uma função fs.readFile()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Não consigo pegar o valor repassado a váriavel `taxValues` fora de `fs.readFile()`

```
const fs = require('fs')
const xml2json = require('xml2json')

const taxValues = {}

function ReadXml(taxValues) {
  fs.readFile( '01.xml', 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
    const xmlNFe = xml2json.toJson(data);

    const convertToJson = JSON.parse(xmlNFe)
    const captureTax = convertToJson.nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.det.imposto

    const icms = captureTax.ICMS.ICMS00.vICMS
    const ipi = captureTax.IPI.IPITrib.vIPI

    taxValues = {
      valorIPI: ipi,
      valorICMS: icms
    }
    console.log(taxValues)
  });
  
  return taxValues
  
}

console.log(taxValues) 

module.exports = { ReadXml, taxValues }
```

Rota:

```
routes.get('/tax', async (req, res) => {
  ReadXml.ReadXml()
  res.send(ReadXml.taxValues)

})
```

Comment: taxValues é uma constante, não pode redefinir o seu valor, use um `let taxValues`

Comment: Já fiz isso, não retorna também

Comment: já viu que sua função é um call back certo? se não esperar o resultado retornar, no momento que passar pelo console.log ainda não deve ter resultado e vai estar vazio

Comment: veja esse exemplo simulando um callback: https://jsfiddle.net/fj7cm43o/1/

Comment: Verifique esta resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10058879/1331430

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na outra resposta que eu dei, eu sugeri o uso de uma versão síncrona da função `fs.readFile`. No entanto, essa solução só é boa se o arquivo for lido uma única vez antes do servidor iniciar a sua execução. Se você precisa ler o arquivo sempre que uma requisição chegar, não é uma boa ideia usar um método síncrono, pois, como eu disse, isso pode bloquear a execução de alguns códigos e deixar outros usuários do servidor esperando sem motivo.

Um jeito de lidar com esse problema seria criar a sua própria função com um callback, o que pode ser feito assim

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const xml2json = require('xml2json');

function getTaxValues(callback) {
  fs.readFile( '01.xml', 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
    const xmlNFe = xml2json.toJson(data);

    const convertToJson = JSON.parse(xmlNFe);
    const captureTax = convertToJson.nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.det.imposto;

    const icms = captureTax.ICMS.ICMS00.vICMS;
    const ipi = captureTax.IPI.IPITrib.vIPI;

    const taxValues = {
      valorIPI: ipi,
      valorICMS: icms,
    };
    
    callback(taxValues);
  });
}

module.exports = getTaxValues;
```

Com a rota sendo

```js
const getTaxValues = require('caminho/para/o/seu/arquivo.js');

routes.get('/tax', (req, res) => {
  getTaxValues(taxValues => {
    res.send(taxValues);
  });
});
```

Essa solução, em particular, é um tanto feia... Tem vários níveis de callbacks encadeados... A melhor solução de fato para esse problema seria utilizando a versão com "promises" da biblioteca `fs` em conjunto com a sintaxe `async` e `await`. Essa seria assim

```js
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const xml2json = require('xml2json');

async function getTaxValues() {
  const data = await fs.readFile('01.xml', 'utf-8');

  const xmlNFe = xml2json.toJson(data);

  const convertToJson = JSON.parse(xmlNFe);

  const captureTax = convertToJson.nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.det.imposto;

  const icms = captureTax.ICMS.ICMS00.vICMS;
  const ipi = captureTax.IPI.IPITrib.vIPI;

  return {
    valorIPI: ipi,
    valorICMS: icms,
  };
}

module.exports = getTaxValues;
```

E a sua rota, então,

```js
const getTaxValues = require('caminho/para/o/seu/arquivo.js');

routes.get('/tax', async (req, res) => {
  const taxValues = await getTaxValues();

  res.send(taxValues);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema que você está enfrentando se dá por conta do entendimento errado da função `readFile` e da atribuição à constante (`const taxValues`).

A função `readFile` recebe o nome do arquivo, a codificação e uma função que é chamada **QUANDO** o arquivo é finalmente lido. Enquanto a leitura não ocorre, o JavaScript executará as instruções seguintes e só depois vai chamar a sua função.

Por exemplo, o código abaixo

```js
let x;

fs.readFile('my-file.txt', 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
  x = data;
});

console.log(x);
```

Vai imprimir na sua cara, um belo **undefined**, pois o `console.log(x)` é executado **ANTES** da função `(err, data) => { x = data; }`.

Outro problema se dá por conta da declaração constante de `taxValues`. Como ela é uma constante, e não uma variável, a linha `taxValues = {valorIPI: ipi, valorICMS: icms }` não vai funcionar, pois você está tentando modificar o valor de uma **constante**.

Para resolver o seu problema, no seu caso específico, você vai precisar da versão síncrona do `fs.readFile`, mas tenha em mente que utilizar código síncrono em excesso é uma **péssima** prática em JavaScript, pois pode levar o código a ser bloqueado.

Dito isso tudo, o seu código pode ser corrigido para

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const xml2json = require('xml2json');

const data = fs.readFileSync( '01.xml', 'utf-8');

const xmlNFe = xml2json.toJson(data);

const convertToJson = JSON.parse(xmlNFe);
const captureTax = convertToJson.nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.det.imposto;

const icms = captureTax.ICMS.ICMS00.vICMS;
const ipi = captureTax.IPI.IPITrib.vIPI;

const taxValues = {
  valorIPI: ipi,
  valorICMS: icms
};

module.exports = taxValues;
```

E, assim, a sua rota ficaria

```js
const taxValues = require('./caminho/para/o/seu/arquivo.js');

routes.get('/tax', (req, res) => {
  res.send(taxValues);
});
```

Comment: Funciona, mas acho que seria mais interessante refatorar para a leitura assíncrona do arquivo, exportando uma função, por exemplo, `readTaxValues`.

Comment: De fato, uma leitura assíncrona é sempre melhor se ela for feita várias vezes. Mas nesse caso, me pareceu não haver necessidade de ler o mesmo arquivo várias vezes, então faz mais sentido ler uma vez só na inicialização do processo do Node.

Comment: De qualquer forma, vou escrever uma outra resposta com um código assíncrono